# how to get and stream phone microphone audio

Tags: react-native

I want to find any package which can provide a microphone audio streaming 
I used react-native-microphone-stream package which only returns 16-bit int numbers

```
import MicStream from 'react-native-microphone-stream';

const listener = MicStream.addListener(data => console.log(data));
MicStream.init({
      bufferSize: 4096,
      sampleRate: 44100,
      bitsPerChannel: 16,
      channelsPerFrame: 1,
});
MicStream.start();

MicStream.stop();
listener.remove();
```